# quotation marks in a javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet, quotation-marks

I wrote a javascript bookmarklet which works well. It is rather long and it contains many single and double quotation marks as in the following toy example:

```
javascript:html="<a href='www.example.com'>example</a>";document.write(html);
```

Now I have to publish it on a web page, that is, I have to insert the javascript string as the url attribute inside an < a > tag in the html source code of the page, so:

`<a href="javascript:...">this is my bookmarklet</a>`

but obviously there is a conflict due to repeated double quotation marks. Is there any simple way I can write the bookmarklet javascript code inside an html code?

Comment: escape one or both types of quotes

Comment: does replacing `"` with `%22` work? (in your href. so it'd be `<a href="javascript:...%22something%22..."></a>`)

Comment: there's also this website, that will encode all possible characters for your url: http://jlpoutre.home.xs4all.nl/BoT/Javascript/Utils/endecode.html

I don't know whether this will work in your situation or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can URL encode characters in bookmarklets and the bookmarklet will work.

But also you can try using a bookmarklet "generator" to make it easier and faster

https://www.google.com/search?q=bookmarklet+generator

Comment: If you found my answer useful and accurate, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This bookmarklet generator was created in 2012 and still works great today: https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/